# How can I get the IDs from this STRING and the word children in it in a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

**DISCLAIMER: I know how to do it when it's JSON, I need to know how to do it as being a *STRING***

I'm trying to get `"ID":`s and `"children":`, I kind of can get both but not in sequence. For now I can only get `"ID":`s or `"children":`s not both, how can I do it, any help is appreciated?

**What I'm getting**:

> 1,3,2

**What I'd like to get**

> 1,children,3,2

**What I'm asking, basically, is to do these two in one (well, in a way that it will bring them in sequence)**.

> var t1 = data.match(/"id":[0-9]+(,|})*/g);
>
> var t2 = data.match(/"children":/g);

**My code is right below:**

```js
var data = '[{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":3},{"name":"child1","id":2}]}]';
var arrays = [];
var t1 = data.match(/"id":[0-9]+(,|})*/g);
//arrays = t1;
for (var x = 0; x < t1.length; x++) {
  arrays.push(t1[x].match(/\d+/));

}
//var t2=data.match(/"children":/g);
alert(arrays /*+"\n\n\n\n\n"+t2*/ );
```

"Live long and prosper"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why it has to be a String? Can you not convert it to json?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for asking, that's the whole point, I can't, I need to know how to do it as a string

Comment: why can't ? aren't u using jquery or whats the point?

Comment: I just need to do these in one: var t1 = data.match(/"id":[0-9]+(,|})*/g);
var t2 = data.match(/"children":/g);

Comment: just add them? this seems silly but if you really needed to why don't you just put an OR in your regex? `data.match(/("id":[0-9]+(,|})*)|"children"/g); `

Comment: @ZekeDroid thank you so much, just put it as answer and I'll be glad to mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using jQuery. I presume you use it because of the tag you created.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/d4a37fbt/)**

```js
var data = '[{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":3},{"name":"child1","id":2}]}]';
var arrays = [];
//convert you string to object
//or you can simply change your first row.
data = $.parseJSON(data);
//function to loop the array
function listNodes(inputVal){
    if(jQuery.isArray( inputVal )){
        $.each(inputVal, function(i,elem){
            arrays.push(elem.id);
            console.log(elem);
            if(jQuery.isArray( elem.children )){
                arrays.push('children');
                listNodes(elem.children);
            }
        })
    }
}
listNodes(data);
alert(arrays /*+"\n\n\n\n\n"+t2*/ );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that's phenomenal, thank you for making it so neat, I hope it will help others in the future.

Comment: Thank you. This can be improved as you go further. :)

Comment: May I ask you something? how can I set a `|` every time the a new separate group is found? http://i.stack.imgur.com/uVk4K.png

Comment: @Calne new group in the sense? you mean element of the first order?

Comment: Kind of, for example, I got this: `1,children,2,3,6,4,children,5` but 4 is not 1's child, it's a separate "group" or so, so every time a group is ended I'd like to add a `|` so the result would be `1,children,2,3,6,|4,children,5` so I'd know that the pipeline separates the groups, Thanks for paying attention :D | Look on the firebug section and the alert on the image and see if you can picture what I'm trying to say http://i.stack.imgur.com/uVk4K.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84678/discussion-between-rejith-r-krishnan-and-calne).